# the participant/reader/writer

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

Why in paragraph below, it is used "the participant" and "the reader" and "the writer"? Can't we write them as "A participant", "A reader", "A writer"?

> Talking about “one of many” is also called “indefinite reference.” We use it when the noun’s exact identity is unknown to one of **the participants: the reader, the writer, or both**. Sometimes it’s not possible for **the reader or the writer** to identify the noun exactly; sometimes it’s not important.

Reference: http://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/articles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the definite article here because we're not just talking about *any* participant or *any* reader or *any* writer, but the *specific* reader or writer involved in this exact case.

The sentence wouldn't exactly be *wrong* with "a", but it's more correct to say "the".

Comment: But I don't undrestand why  they are specific?

Comment: "to one of" refers to one specific person, even if unidentified in context. So use *the*.